# Android Localisation : pt_BR strings are not displayed

Tags: android

I am trying to display string of pt_BR(Português-Brasileiro) in my android application.I have copied all the strings in values-pt_BR.But the respective strings are not displayed when i change my device language to  Português -Brazil.

If i place the string in values-pt (Português) the string are displayed for both the languages i.e for Português-portugal and Português -Brazil. which is wrong i feel.

But in the code if i print Locale.getDefault() it prints pt_BR for Português -Brazil and pt_PT for Português-portugal.

How to differentiate these two languages in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) it seems that they add a `r` character in the folder like the following:

`values-pt-rBR`. (try also without that `r` character, but make sure you use `-` character instead of `_`.)

Maybe this way it will work.

Hope it helps :)